# Ruby on Rails + Carrierwave: Why is the image_tag on my show page returning an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails & [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). I get this error when I try to show an image file that a user has uploaded:

> "Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #
>   Did you mean?  to_xml"

The error is specifically linked to this line of code:

```
<%= image_tag @review.photo %>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working because the file is being added to the database correctly. I can see it in my Public > Uploads folder.

Here's what I've got in...

My model:

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @review do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Review title" %>
 # other fields
 <%= f.input :photo %>
 <%= f.button :submit, class: "submit-button", value: "Save Review" %>
<% end %>
```

My show page:

```
<%= image_tag @review.photo %>
```

My controller:

```
def form_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:title, ..others.. , :photo)
end
```

The PhotoUploader class is as default:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

Any help is massively appreciated. :-)

[image: My error message]

Comment: Don't you have to do something like `image_tag @review.photo_url`

Answer (score 0):

The example in the docs: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave shows that you would call an `image_tag` thusly:

```
<%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
```

Assuming you haven't configured the path otherwise you should be able to do:

```
<%= image_tag @review.photo_url, alt: 'Your photo description' %>
```

(Make sure to use an `alt` tag for accessibility purposes)